# How i18n works for Docusaurus src/components?

Tags: internationalization, docusaurus

I have i18n perfectly setup and working for themes and plugins of a Docusaurus website.

But for the homepage, I have a component `Foo.js` located in `src/components/Foo.js`.

It contains a `const Bar = 'happy';`

Is a text string that will be part of the HTML returned by the component and I want it translated.

I guess it should be possible; in the documentation is stated:

> JSON is used to translate: Your React code: standalone React pages
> in src/pages, or other components

and

> `code.json  # Any text label present in the React code`

The `Bar` text is not extracted with `docusaurus write-translations`.

Should I add manually to `code.json` ? If yes, which is the correct key to use?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `Translate` component and use it to wrap translatable strings in your custom code.

Details and examples can be found in the [Translate your React code](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/i18n/tutorial#translate-your-react-code) section in the Docusaurus i18n documentation.

For your example you'd end up with something like:

```js
import Translate from '@docusaurus/Translate';
const Bar = <Translate id="mcall.foo.bar">happy</Translate>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction, perfect, got it, appreciated.
I just couldn't find before the relevant piece of info in the documentation.